# How to use table without model in hasMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many

is that possible to use direct table name in hasMany. for example

```
public function Permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('TABLE NAME');
}
```

I have table named PERMISSION but don't have a model of this table, but i want to use this table in hasmany.

Comment: No, it's not possible if you want to use it in a relationship.

Comment: No, because the relations are part of Eloquent, which is built on models.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have time to elaborate right now but please checkout `belongsToMany` relationships. This method takes `table` as a second argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a model for that table

```
php artisan make:model Permisson
```

then add the table name to the model class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permisson extends Model
{
    protected $table = "table_name";
}
```

and add the relation

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Permisson::class)
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 13):

Relations in Laravel are a part of [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) which is built on the use of models.
So, no, it is not possible to use relations without making models for them.